# How to match the following regex python?

Tags: python, regex

How to match the following with regex?

```
string1 = '1.0) The Ugly Duckling (TUD) (10 Dollars)'
string2 = '1.0) Little 1 Red Riding Hood (9.50 Dollars)'
```

I am trying the following:

```
groupsofmatches = re.match('(?P<booknumber>.*)\)([ \t]+)?(?P<item>.*)(\(.*\))?\(.*?((\d+)?(\.\d+)?).*([ \t]+)?Dollars(\))?', string1)
```

The issue is when I apply it to string2 it works fine, but when I apply the expression to string1, I am unable to get the "m.group(name)" because of the "(TUD)" part. I want to use a single expression that works for both strings.

I expect:

```
booknumber = 1.0
item = The Ugly Duckling (TUD)
```

Comment: Should `(TUD)` be captured or not?

Comment: (TUD) should be captured as part of the "name", updated post.

Comment: And by `name` you mean `item`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `.*` matches greedily, and it may be consuming too much of the string.  Printing all of the match groups will make this more obvious:

```
import re

string1 = '1.0) The Ugly Duckling (TUD) (10 Dollars)'
string2 = '1.0) Little 1 Red Riding Hood (9.50 Dollars)'

result = re.match(r'(.*?)\)([ \t]+)?(?P<item>.*)\(.*?(?P<dollaramount>(\d+)?(\.\d+)?).*([ \t]+)?Dollars(\))?', string1)

print repr(result.groups())
print result.group('item')
print result.group('dollaramount')
```

[Changing them to `*?` makes the match the minimum](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

This can be expensive in some RE engines, so you can also write eg `\([^)]*\)` to match all the parenthesis.  If you're not processing a lot of text it probably doesn't matter.

btw, you should really use raw strings (ie `r'something'`) for regexps, to avoid surprising backslash behaviour, and to give the reader a clue.

I see you had this group `(\(.*?\))?` which presumably was cutting out the `(TUD)`, but if you actually want that in the title, just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You could impose some heavier restrictions on your repeated characters:

```
groupsofmatches = re.match('([^)]*)\)[ \t]*(?P<item>.*)\([^)]*?(?P<dollaramount>(?:\d+)?(?:\.\d+)?)[^)]*\)$', string1)
```

This will make sure that the numbers are taken from the last set of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it as:

```
num, name, value = re.match(r'(.+?)\) (.*?) \(([\d.]+) Dollars\)', s2).groups()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it with a [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rI3iG3)

`(?P<booknumber>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\)\s+(?P<item>.*?)\s+\(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s+Dollars\)`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use regex pattern

```
(?P<booknumber>[^)]*)\)\s+(?P<item>.*\S)\s+\((?!.*\()(?P<amount>\S+)\s+Dollars?\)
```